# How to find price from udemy website with web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup package of python to find the price of courses. Using beautiful soup I am getting price in dollars, and when I convert it in rupees it is different.

```
price in udemy website : 700
price by beautiful soup : 13.99$
```

I have tried to find logic by calculating different courses ratio but it did not work.
Here is my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.udemy.com/course/python-data-science-machine-learning-bootcamp/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for sp in soup.find_all('span',class_='price-text__current'):
   print(sp)
```

I am getting this output :

```
<span class="price-text__current" data-purpose="discount-price-text">
<span class="sr-only">Current price:</span> $13.99
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: The issue is with converting from dollar to rupees or in extracting the details ?

Comment: In udemy site, it auto-tracks your location, giving you the price in rupees. So in requests, it does track Ip address, but also, you can specify your location in the url, to recieve the price in rupees.

Comment: you location provides the format for price to be shown. So if you are using any vpn, kindly avoid it

Comment: I get <span class="price-text__current" data-purpose="discount-price-text">
<span class="sr-only">Current price:</span> ₹385
</span> since i do the requests from India

Comment: Hi @JoshuaVarghese , earlier I was connected to vpn. After disconnect I am getting ₹385 but actual is ₹525 now. Do you know why??

Comment: @VipinSC its 385 :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to send `headers` with your request:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# For French people:
hd = {'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR'}
page = requests.get('https://www.udemy.com/course/python-data-science-machine-learning-bootcamp/',
                    headers = hd)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for sp in soup.find_all('span',class_='price-text__current'):
    print(sp)

# For US people:
hd = {'Accept-Language': 'en,en-US'}
page = requests.get('https://www.udemy.com/course/python-data-science-machine-learning-bootcamp/',
                    headers = hd)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for sp in soup.find_all('span',class_='price-text__current'):
    print(sp)
```

output:

```
<span class="price-text__current" data-purpose="discount-price-text">
<span class="sr-only">Prix actuel :</span> 15,99 €
</span>
<span class="price-text__current" data-purpose="discount-price-text">
<span class="sr-only">Current price:</span> €12.99
</span>
```

Note however that the responses seems to vary after requests afer requests. The website is perhaps tracking you on the server side. You also have to play with header to obtain the value you want.

Comment: I have tried to change the headers of different countries. But still I am not getting correct price. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In udemy site, it auto-tracks your location, giving you the price in rupees. So in requests, the url tracks your location from your IP_Address, which can produce different results if you use a VPN.
As @pyOliv said, When You use `Accept-Language`, you aren't actually setting the location for the request, but the language in which the data must be received.
So if you do the request from India, you get:

```
<span class="price-text__current" data-purpose="discount-price-text">
<span class="sr-only">Current price:</span> ₹385
</span>
```

Which is the real price:
[image]

Comment: I have checked it again, udemy is showing 525 and using python i am getting 385.

Comment: @VipinSC my image tells its 385